# How to format code to use the specified `tabSize` with the built-in formatter?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, indentation, vscode-extensions

I have the following [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script sample, notice the code is indented by a *single* space:

```
#z::
 MsgBox The Win-Z hotkey was pressed.
 Gosub MySubroutine
 return

MySubroutine:
 Sleep 1000
 return
```

I searched through the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) but didn't find a usable formatter extension for AHK scripts.

I've configured `"editor.tabSize": 2`, is there a way to format the code to use the specified `tabSize` with the VSCode built-in formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131598).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an [AutoHotKey Plus extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-autohotkey-plus) that includes formatting that seems to adhere to the Visual Studio Code built-in formatter setting for the tab size.  I set my tab size to two and performed the format shortcut using the extension (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>):

[image: indent gif]

It seems though that certain keywords, such as `return` will cling to the margin, presumably because the formatter for the extension interprets this as the standard convention for AHK (in my opinion though, I like the way it looks).

Comment: Note, I also had [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-autohotkey) AHK extension installed too.

Comment: There's also an [AutoHotkey Plus Plus](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mark-wiemer.vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus), LOL.

Comment: @WenfangDu oh boy, I wonder if that is built off of the regular *plus* one!

Comment: [It is](https://github.com/mark-wiemer/vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus). Just tried both, the formatters broke my code and are unconfigurable, unfortunately.

Comment: Other than that, AHK++ is a pretty good one.

Comment: @WenfangDu does it work as you expect? What did the singular plus one do to break your script?

Comment: The formatter? No, the formatters of AHK+ and AHK++ are both unconfigurable. Broke my formatting I should say.